# Trying to upgrade php on WHM/Cpanel and I am getting errors

Tags: apache-2.2, php

After I recompile Apache for the newer version of php. Everything goes fine, but I get the following php errors: Warning: main() [function.main]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CDT/-5.0/DST'.

And PDO Class not found.

In the php.ini file the following are included. extension=pdo.so extension=pdo_sqlite.so extension=sqlite.so extension=pdo_mysql.so extension=uploadprogress.so

Any Ideas.

Answer (score 1):

add the line

```
date.timezone = America/Chicago
```

to your php file (/usr/local/lib/php.ini)
regarding the PDO issue if you installed via PECL then you should reinstall the plugins to make them work correctly, also you may need to recompile apache and php and enable pdo in the easyapache update - http://forums.cpanel.net/f34/fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found-116629.html